# Slider based on Networkx node attribute value with Bokeh

Tags: bokeh, networkx

I am attempting to develop a slider which will limit the number of nodes visible in a network graph based on the value of a node's attribute. The below Pandas DataFrame (df) represents the nodes, and the node's associated attributes (count information).

```
source   target   source_count   target_count
A        C        15             10
A        D        15             20
A        E        15             30
B        F        25             10
B        G        25             20
B        H        25             30
```

I have used the following code to generate a network graph for the nodes and their associated attributes.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox,layout, 
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, 
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, value,PanTool, LabelSet, Legend, ColumnDataSource,Circle,Plot, Range1d, MultiLineBoxSelectTool,ResetTool,LassoSelectTool,Slider
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx, NodesAndLinkedEdges, EdgesAndLinkedNodes


df = pd.DataFrame({
            "source":["A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B"],
            "target":["C", "D", "E", "F", "G","H"],
            "source_count":["15", "15", "15", "25","25","25"]
            "target_count":["10", "20", "30", "10","20","30"]
})

net_graph = from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target')

#assign attributes
for index, row in df.iterrows():
net_graph.nodes[row['source']]['yearly_count'] = row['source_count']
net_graph.nodes[row['target']]['yearly_count'] = row['target_count']


graph_plot= Plot(plot_width=800, plot_height=600,
            x_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1))

node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Name", "@index"),("Yearly Count", "@yearly_count")])

graph_plot.add_tools(node_hover_tool)
graph_setup = from_networkx(net_graph, nx.spring_layout, scale=1, center=(0, 0))

graph_setup.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=20,fill_color = 'blue') 
graph_setup.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="red", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=1)

graph_plot.renderers.append(graph_setup)

output_file("test_1.html")
show(graph_plot)
```

The slider I am trying to would use the `yearly_count` attribute to limit the number of nodes on display. I know that Bokeh allows the embedding of a JavaScript Callback, however, I have not seen a use-case integrated with NetworkX.

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can run your app with `bokeh serve` then I would try:

```
from bokeh.models import Slider

graph_plot= Plot()
graph_setup.node_renderer.glyph = Circle()
graph_setup.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine()

def callback(attr, old, new):
    //filter your data here to show less nodes and edges based 
    graph_setup.node_renderer.data_source.data = data
    graph_setup.edge_renderer.data_source.data = data

slider = Slider()
slider.on_change('value', callback)
```

If you want to run a Bokeh standalone app then replace slider callback with:

```
code = """
    //filter your data here to show less nodes and edges
    graph_setup.node_renderer.data_source.data = data;
    graph_setup.edge_renderer.data_source.data = data; """

callback = CustomJS(args = dict(graph_setup = graph_setup, data = data), code = code)
slider = Slider()
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

See complete JS callback example below:

```
import networkx as nx
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, TapTool, OpenURL, HoverTool, CustomJS, Slider, Column
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx, EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from dask.dataframe.core import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

data = {'source': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'target': ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'source_count': [15, 15, 15, 25, 25, 25], 'target_count': [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
net_graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    net_graph.nodes[row['source']]['yearly_count'] = row['source_count']
    net_graph.nodes[row['target']]['yearly_count'] = row['target_count']

graph_plot = Plot(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 600, x_range = Range1d(-1.1, 1.1), y_range = Range1d(-1.1, 1.1))

node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips = [("Name", "@index"), ("Yearly Count", "@yearly_count")])
graph_plot.add_tools(node_hover_tool)

graph_setup = from_networkx(net_graph, nx.spring_layout, scale = 1, center = (0, 0))
graph_setup.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size = 20, fill_color = 'blue')
graph_setup.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color = "red", line_alpha = 0.8, line_width = 1)

graph_plot.renderers.append(graph_setup)

code = """ 
    var new_start = start.slice();
    var new_end = end.slice();
    new_index = end.slice();

    new_start = new_start.splice(0, cb_obj.value)
    new_end = new_end.splice(0, cb_obj.value)
    new_index = ['A'].concat(new_end)

    new_data_edge = {'start': new_start, 'end': new_end};
    new_data_nodes = {'index': new_index};
    graph_setup.edge_renderer.data_source.data = new_data_edge; 
    graph_setup.node_renderer.data_source.data = new_data_nodes; 
"""
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(graph_setup = graph_setup,
                                start = df['source'].values,
                                end = df['target'].values), code = code)
slider = Slider(title = 'Slider', start = 1, end = 6, value = 6)
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = Column(graph_plot, slider)
show(layout)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your time and answer. I'm having difficulty rendering the slider on my Bokeh plot. When I attempt to call the `slider` in a layout I am receiving the following error `TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I see. Then you need to pass the data to the callback before creating the dataframe.

Comment: By this do do you passing data to `filtered_data` prior to creating the dataframe?

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the updated answer, it works perfectly. One final question, is there a way to call the df columns with the `code` section. My full dataframe has over 100 `sources` and 'target' nodes. Thanks again.

Comment: Just split `df` into multiple arguments like: `target  = df['target'].values`, `source_count = df['source_count'].values` etc... and pass them to your callback

Comment: I created the following arguments `target = df['target'] values source = df['source'].values` 
`code = """ 
    new_data_edge = {'start': source, 'end': target}
    new_data_nodes = {'index': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']}
    graph_setup.edge_renderer.data_source.data = new_data_edge; 
    graph_setup.node_renderer.data_source.data = new_data_nodes; 
"""` However I am unsure what to pass in for `new_data_nodes`. Thanks again

Comment: I am not familiar with node graphs. I my example I analysed the data structure and came up with `A + target` array so you could try:  `['A'] + target` where 'A' is your central node label. My code is just an example how to change the number of nodes. You will need to do real data filtering and link the slider value to number of nodes in your graph

Comment: Sorry, I don't have your data so it is hard to assist you better. I connected the slider to the graph. See updated code and image.

Comment: Tony, thanks very much for your time and answer, it works perfectly! I am very new to JavaScript, and Bokeh JS Callbacks. If I was to add additional sources (for example `B` in original df) would I have to replicate the following line of code for each source -  `new_index = ['A'].concat(new_end)`

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Bokeh uses strict mode for JavaScript ([see release log](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#use-strict-for-customjs)), which implies that `code` from Tony's accepted answer does not work for Bokeh version 2.0.0 and upwards. Only a few small explicit declarations of variables are needed for the code to work for newer Bokeh versions:

```
code = ''' 
    var new_start = start.slice();
    var new_end = end.slice();
    var new_index = end.slice();

    new_start = new_start.splice(0, cb_obj.value)
    new_end = new_end.splice(0, cb_obj.value)
    new_index = ['A'].concat(new_end)

    var new_data_edge = {'start': new_start, 'end': new_end};
    var new_data_nodes = {'index': new_index};
    graph_setup.edge_renderer.data_source.data = new_data_edge; 
    graph_setup.node_renderer.data_source.data = new_data_nodes;
'''
```